# Option for email alerts to not show questions you've already answered/viewed

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

I like and use the email alert option for certain tags, but I get emailed on questions I have already seen and/or answered and/or commented on.  It would be great to have an option to filter out ones I have answered / commented on.  Filtering out ones I have viewed would also be good but I am not sure if you are logging views per user or not.